# right-aligned textarea's cursor placement following whitespace

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea with right-aligned text, and if the cursor is at the end of a line and whitespace is added, the whitespace shows up as expected, however the cursor remains adjacent to the previous non-whitespace character.

Is there anyway to make the cursor appear after newly entered whitespace in this context (like it does when the textarea is left-aligned)?

```css
textarea {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Have you tried `direction: rtl;` on the textarea?

Comment: That seems to cause the cursor to appear on the far left of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify `white-space` inside an element. I.E

```css
textarea {
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `dir="rtl"` attribute:

```html
<textarea dir="rtl"></textarea>
```

Comment: I did try that, however, the cursor ends up appearing at the far left of the line, despite the fact that the text is being added on the right